# functools reduce In-Place modifies original dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, functools

I currently facing the issue that "functools.reduce(operator.iadd,...)" alters the original input. E.g.

I have a simple dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame([[['A', 'B']], [['C', 'D']]])

```
        0
0  [A, B]
1  [C, D]
```

Applying the iadd operator leads to following result:

```
functools.reduce(operator.iadd, df[0])
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Now, the original df changed to

```
              0
0  [A, B, C, D]
1        [C, D]
```

Also copying the df using df.copy(deep=True) beforehand does not help.

Has anyone an idea to overcome this issue? 
THX, Lazloo

Comment: From Unutbu's answer, i realized it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `operator.add` instead of `operator.iadd`:

```
In [8]: functools.reduce(operator.add, df[0])
Out[8]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
        0
0  [A, B]
1  [C, D]
```

After all, `operator.iadd(a, b)` is the same as `a += b`. So it modifies `df[0]`. In contrast, `operator.add(a, b)` *returns* `a + b`, so there is no modification of `df[0]`.

---

Or, you could compute the same quantity using `df[0].sum()`:

```
In [39]: df[0].sum()
Out[39]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

---

The [docs for `df.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) warns:

> When `deep=True`, data is copied **but actual Python objects
>   will not be copied recursively**, only the reference to the object.

Since `df[0]` contains Python lists, the lists are not copied even with `df.copy(deep=True)`. This is why modifying the copy still affects `df`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @unutbu's good answer, you can also use the `int.__add__` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[['A', 'B']], [['C', 'D']]])
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x).__add__(y), df[0])
print(df)
```

And You can see that it is:

```
        0
0  [A, B]
1  [C, D]
```

For output!!!

Comment: A custom lambda is unnecessary and slower than just specifying an operator